# Adding caption in pgfplotstabletypeset

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

How do I add caption into my codes? I have tried searching around online, but could not successfully adding caption in my table.

Here are my codes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
     col sep=comma,
     string type,
     every head row/.style={
         before row=\toprule, 
         after row=\midrule,
     },
     every last row/.style={
         after row=\bottomrule,
     },    
     font=\scriptsize,
]{price.csv}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As always you can use the `table` environment with a caption or the `caption` package with `\captionof{table}{CAPTION}`. Dependent on your caption's position you should consider adding some vertical space around it.

Btw: Without a test file one can only use a sample table as I did in my example.

[image: caption]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption here}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
     col sep=comma,
     string type,
     every head row/.style={
         before row=\toprule, 
         after row=\midrule,
     },
     every last row/.style={
         after row=\bottomrule,
     },    
     font=\scriptsize,
]{
1,2
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```